# Verilog booth algorithm adding and subtracting

Tags: verilog

```
module calculator(state,U,V,X,X_1,multiplicant,multiplier,count);
input [1:0] state;
input [3:0] multiplicant,multiplier;

output reg [3:0] U,V,X;
output reg X_1;
output reg[2:0] count;

wire [7:0] ASR;
wire [4:0] CSR;
wire [3:0] sum, sub;


always @ (state or count)
begin
U<=4'b0;
V<=4'b0;
X<=multiplier;
X_1<=1'b0;
count<=3'b0;
if(state==2'b01)
begin
    case({X[0],X_1})
    2'b00:
    begin
        {U,V}<=ASR;
        {X,X_1}<=CSR;
    end

    2'b11:
    begin
        {U,V}<=ASR;
        {X,X_1}<=CSR;
    end

    2'b01:
    begin
        U<=sum;
        {U,V}<=ASR;
        {X,X_1}<=CSR;
    end

    2'b10:
    begin
        U<=sub;
        {U,V}<=ASR;
        {X,X_1}<=CSR;
    end
    endcase
    count <= count +1;
end
end


rca U0_rca4(.a(multiplicant),.b(U),.ci(1'b0),.s(sum));
rca U1_rca4(.a(U),.b(~multiplicant),.ci(1'b1),.s(sub));
ASR8 U2_ASR8({U,V},1'b1,ASR);
CSR5 U3_CSR5({X,X_1},1'b1,CSR);
endmodule
```

This is my code, the case 2'b01 and case 2'b10 doesn't work. Actually, shifting works well but adding rca's sum or sub to 'U' doesn't work. Why does it happen? I need explain. Or can I modify my code better? I have to make 4bit*4bit -> 8bit result multiplier

Comment: which shifting works? there are **no** shifts in your code. Do **not** use `non-blocking` assignments there.

Comment: @Serge Actually, ASR and CSR means shifting. ASR is Arithmetic shift, CSR is Circular shift

Comment: ASR. CSR are just wires, simple variables. whatever you name them, does not make them shifting or anything else. So, what does it mean that it works?

Comment: @Serge there are modules for shift operation. I made shift modules and added them to project file. You can see modules that output are connected to wire at last lines.

Comment: There is asynchronous feedback on `count`. At minimum the count logic needs to be moved into a separate `always @(posedge clock)`, or make the whole always block clock sensitive. Also, combinational logic needs the full sensitive list and use blocking (`=`) assignments; not non-blocking (`<=`). `always @ (state or count)` is an incomplete sensitivity list as it is missing `ASR`, `CSR`, and other signals. Instead of writing the sensitivity list like it is 1995, use `always @*` ( or synonymous `always @(*)`) that was added in 2001 for auto sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple issues with your code.

First of all there are no clocks. The case statement looks full and is a combinational logic, however 'counter <= counter + 1` is not a combinational logic and requires a flop.

you are using non-blocking assignments '<=' all over the places, making your model simulating not as expected in any case, and also probably causing glitches and races in simulation. Please review the chapter about use of blockling/non-blocking assignments.

Now for the cases `01` and `10` you have multiple assignments to the `U` variable:

```
2'b01:
begin
    U<=sum;   // << here is assighment #1
    {U,V}<=ASR; // << here is assignment #2
    {X,X_1}<=CSR;
end
```

So, you just overwrite it in the next assignment, therefore, sum (and sub in 10) do not take any effect.